# C++ searching through memory for a binary sequence that match a pattern

Tags: c++, arrays, regex, memory, pattern-matching

I'm sure this question has already been asked and solved somewhere, but I actually didn't really find anything that works for me.

I'm trying to write a DLL which needs to find something in the .text section of an application. I think I can manage locating the .text section which contains what I want, so I think from that, I should be able to get a byte array (unsigned char *?) containing the whole .text section (?)

Now, since there are pointers everywhere, I figured I needed to use a regular expression to ignore certain bytes that might change depending on the version of the application.

So what would be the best way to find my pattern?
An example of such pattern:
"48 8d ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? e8"

Comment: You can just use simple `find` for `48 8d` bytes and then check for `e8` on each match.

Answer (score 1):

Using a regex is more work than necessary. What you want is a way of specifying a pattern of bytes with a marker for "match anything".

Unfortunately you can't use any `unsigned char` value for as all the available values (from `0x0` to `0xff`) are possible matches. One solution might be to use a `uint16_t` instead of `uint8_t` for this and use any value above `0xff` to have special meaning. For your example let's say you settles on `0xffff` for this:

```c
const uint16_t pattern[] = { 0x48, 0x8d, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xe8 };
```

You now have to do the match byte by byte (you can no longer use something like `memcmp`, or `find` directly):

```c
#define pattern_match_anything  0xffff

// Checks if the text[start_index:text_size] region matches pattern.
bool check_at_index(const uint8_t *text, size_t text_size, size_t start_index, const uint16_t *pattern)
{
    size_t pattern_index = 0;
    
    // Some bounds checks omitted for simplicity.
    for (size_t i = start_index; i < text_size; i++)
    {
        if (pattern[pattern_index] == pattern_match_anything)
        {
            pattern_index++;
            continue;
        }
        
        if (text[i] != pattern[pattern_index]) return false;

        pattern_index++;
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Or you could use a `std::optional<unsigned char>` for the pattern.

Comment: @MSalters yes, you can. You still have to handle each byte independently, which is the main drawback in this approach.

Comment: True, but you could solve that by using `std::search` and a custom predicate which handles `std::optional<unsigned char>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use *regular expressions* for this, though it might not be the fastest way, it depends on your needs. Do you just want to find the position? Do you want to extract a copy of the area of memory? Or just some of the memory locations from inside the match?

Here is a `std::regex` option:

```
char const* find_chunk(char const* const beg, char const* const end)
{
    static std::regex const re{R"(\x48\x8D....\xE8)", std::regex_constants::optimize};

    std::cmatch m;
    if(!std::regex_search(beg, end, m, re))
        return end;

    return m[0].first;
}
```

A likely faster way would be to manually check for the pattern parts individually something like this:

```
char const* find_chunk(char const* const beg, char const* const end)
{
    static char const match[] = {'\x48', '\x8D'};

    auto found = std::search(beg, end, std::begin(match), std::end(match));

    if(std::distance(found, end) > 6 && found[6] == '\xE8')
        return found;

    return end;
}
```

As mentionned in the comments another approach would be to use `std::optional<char>` like this:

```
char const* find_chunk(char const* const beg, char const* const end)
{
    static std::optional<char> const m[] = {{'\x48'}, {'\x8D'}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {'\xE8'}};

    return std::search(beg, end, std::begin(m), std::end(m), [](auto a, auto b){
        if(!b.has_value())
            return true;
        return a == b.value();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir, I'm actually looking for a memory location inside the match. I think I'm going to use your regex option.